# How do I fix screen tearing? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I just installed Ubuntu around 2 weeks ago. But now whenever watch videos online it gets screen tearing. How can I fix this? I'm not sure what the command to get info on my system is so sorry for not giving more info :/

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Intel
HP computer

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have Nvidia Graphics card, in your laptop/desktop. Just go to your nvidia server setting, go to your PRIME profiles, and select NVIDIA-on-Demand.
Restart.
It fixed the screen-tearing for me.